# How can disable or enable cache in angular (iis server)?

Tags: angular, iis

How can `disable` cache for  `html` file and  `enable` cache for `*.js` and `*.css` files in angular project or in iis `web.config` file?

Comment: This subject is kinda wide. Can you be more specific please ? You can configure your Apache/Nginx to choose which file should be cached or not by the browser. You can configure angular-cli to make each build reset cache (by adding an hash to each file). The only html file is the index.html, and should never be cached, but this is not handled by angular.

Comment: i need cache all files else index file . I cant set it in with service Worker angular ?

Comment: It has nothing to do with service worker. You cannot manually reset cache in your js code. It is all about your build, and apache/nginx config.

Comment: my project publish it in iis server, and how can set it in web config file?

Comment: Again, this is a wide question. We would have to know what is your actual config, environments etc... You should try finding resources on Google to learn about iis cache... Then we can help you find out what you did wrong, but we cannot do it for you.

Comment: If you configure caching in iis, you can only use Output Caching, does this meet your needs? If not, then you can only configure caching in angular.

Comment: @samwu how can disable cache home page in Output Caching? i need home page not cached but others cached

Comment: It is not possible to just disable the cache of the home page in iis, for information about Output Caching you can refer to this link: [Output Caching](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2012-R2-and-2012/hh831613(v=ws.11)?redirectedfrom=MSDN).

Comment: @samwu then iis caching not work for me. have another sulotion?

Answer (score 0):

You can configure caching option in angular.json file like below :

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "cli": {
    "cache": {
      "enabled": false // true or false
    }
  },
  "projects": {}
}
```

As of my knowledge, you cannot manually do anything with javascript code. All these are build-time configurations. If you are trying something with an HTTP request

You can specify in the request header itself like below :

```
headers = new Headers({
        'Cache-Control':  'no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate, post- 
                            check=0, pre-check=0',
        'Pragma': 'no-cache',
        'Expires': '0'
    });
```

Comment: in `angular.json` file cant set disable some and enable some ?

Comment: These are build time configurations which you cannot change on fly as of my knowelage

Comment: have sulotion just disabe cache just fro home page and cached other pages?

Comment: I'm not aware of any. Appreciate if you can upvote the answer and mark it as correct.